# An intriguing differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently came across the following differential equation:

$$(y')^4 = 1 - y^2$$

I am unable to see any way forward, having only found the trivial $y=1$ as a solution. How can one solve this equation?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $y=-1$ will also work.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives implicit solutions in terms of the hypergeometric 2F1 function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dsolve+%28y%27%29%5E4%3D1-y%5E2. To verify this, one switches the variables to get the ODE $x'(y) = (1-y^2)^{-1/4}$. I would not expect to obtain an analytical expression for $y(x)$, but the implicit solutions may suffice for numerical work.

Comment: This differential equation gives the inverse of an [EllipticE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=EllipticE) function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch variables to make
$$[x']^4=\frac 1{1-y^2}$$ which will give the "nice"
$$x=c_1\pm y \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};y^2\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function. This would be almoast impossible to inverse.

We can make decent approximations for the case $c_1=0$ and the positive branch since
$$y \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};y^2\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}{(2 n+1) \Gamma (n+1)}y^{2n+1}$$  Truncating to some order and using series reversion
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \,x^{2n+1}$$ the $a_n$'s forming the sequence
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{12},-\frac{1}{96},-\frac{23}{8064},-\frac{1195}{1161216},-\frac{21
   985}{51093504},-\frac{242057}{1226244096},-\frac{9943859}{103004504064},-\frac{1
   63085399}{3296144130048},-\frac{59258145865}{2254562584952832}\right\}$$  This is probably much faster than a series solution.